# How to click on checkbox with ElementNotInteractableException using Selenium WebDriver Java?

Tags: selenium, checkbox, webdriver, click, element

I would like to click on checkbox but it keep saying that element is not interactable.
I actually tried .click, javascriptexecutor, actions, wait until, thread.sleep, scroll. Even when I try context click on the checkbox it says that element is not interactable.
Any other ideas?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Single Checkbox Demo</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p> Clicking on the checkbox will display a success message. Keep an eye on it</p>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected" value="">Click on this check box</label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Success - Check box is checked</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here is the url: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-checkbox-demo.html

Checkbox code:

```
@FindBy(id = "isAgeSelected")
private WebElement checkboxFirstExample;
public checkboxDemo checkboxFirstEx(){
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", checkboxFirstExample);
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkboxFirstExample);
  return this;
}
```

Whole code:

```
public class checkboxDemo extends baseSeleniumClass {

@FindBy(xpath = "//ul[@id='treemenu']//a[contains(text(),'Input Forms')]")
private WebElement inputFormsMenu;

@FindBy(xpath = "//li[@style='display: list-item;']//a[@href='./basic-checkbox-demo.html']")
private WebElement checkboxDemo;

@FindBy(id = "isAgeSelected")
private WebElement checkboxFirstExample;

@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='txtAge']")
private WebElement ageSelected;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='button'][@id='check1']")
private WebElement checkboxAll;

private seleniumHelper helper;

private WebDriver driver;

public checkboxDemo(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.helper = new seleniumHelper(driver);
    this.driver = driver;
}

public checkboxDemo checkboxDemostart(){

    checkboxDemo.click();
    return this;
}

public checkboxDemo checkboxFirstEx(){

        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", checkboxFirstExample);
        checkboxFirstExample.click();
        System.out.println("3. " + ageSelected.getText() + " - First checkbox passed");
    return this;
}

public checkboxDemo checkboxSecondEx(){
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", checkboxAll);
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkboxAll);
    System.out.println("4. " + checkboxAll.getAttribute("value") + " - All checkboxes are selected");

    return this;
}

public checkboxDemo inputMenu(){
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", inputFormsMenu);
    return this;
}
```

}

Comment: please add html

Comment: Please add your code also

Comment: Using this annotated FindBy, make sure you are using PageFactory pattern on this. If you don't pass the Webdriver instance, obviously your script won't do anything.


It would be better if you can show whole code of this class

Answer (score 0):

```
@FindBy(id = "isAgeSelected")
private WebElement checkboxFirstExample;
public checkboxDemo checkboxFirstEx(){
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: \"center\"});", checkboxFirstExample);
    checkboxFirstExample.click();
  return this;
}
```

use id , 'isAgeSelected' . You should click the input tag

xpath :

```
//input[@id="isAgeSelected"]
```

CSS:

```
input[id="isAgeSelected"]
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. As well as find by xpath, partial link text, link text.

Comment: which language are you suing , use find By.id

Comment: you don't have to use execute script

Comment: WebElement checkboxFirstExample = driver.findElement(By.id("isAgeSelected"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkboxFirstExample);
still element not interactable

Comment: Use element.click() as in the updated code

Comment: when I use driver.findElement(By.id("isAgeSelected")).click();  there is still the same issue

Comment: element.click(); when I'm trying to find element with xpath and css still returns the same issue
I had the same problem a few days ago and  fixed it with executor but  worked only for another few days.  Nothing has changed in html and my code but click just stopped working so I tried to use other methods but it keep saying that element is not interactable.

Comment: @DominikRosa could you try the updated code ?

Comment: I tried and there is still the same issue.